# ListAnimate for Möbius band

Tags: graphics

I would like to use ListAnimate for this. I tried it and it did not work.

```
x[u_, t_] := (u Sin[t/2] + 1) Cos[t];
y[u_, t_] := (u Sin[t/2] + 1) Sin[t];
z[u_, t_] := u Cos[t/2];
gif = Animate[
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[{x[u, t], y[u, t], z[u, t]}], {u, -1/2, 1/2}, {t, 0, tf},
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
   ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   Mesh -> None],
  {tf, 0.01, 2 Pi, 0.01}, AnimationRepetitions -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: `I tried it and it did not work.` this is not a very good description of the problem. but it `works` for me using 12.3.1. but may be what does not work for you is not what I am seeing since I do not know what it is that did not work.

Comment: Does not run on MM 12.3.0

Comment: @DanielHuber I just tried it on 12.3.0 also. It runs no problem. All on windows 10.

Comment: For v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 it works.

Comment: Work in 12.0 and 12.3.1 in Linux and Win 10.